# How to name dataframes dynamically in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, dataframe

I have an excel file which contains more than 30 sheets. However the operation that I do on each sheet remains the same more or less. But my objective is to create a separate dataframe for each sheet, so that I can refer in the future

This is what I tried but it throws an error

```
xls = pd.ExcelFile('DC_Measurement.xlsx')
sheets = xls.sheet_names
for s in sheets:
    print(s)
    'df '+ s = pd.read_excel(xls, sheet_name=s)
```

So, it's like I want 30 dataframes to be created and each dataframe will have the sheet name as the suffix name. I tried using the "+" operator but it didn't help either. It threw an error message as shown below

```
  SyntaxError: can't assign to operator
```

How can I create dataframes on the fly and name them ?

Comment: You can create a dictionary with key as `df_{}.format(s)` and val as `pd.read_excel(xls, sheet_name=s)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create a variable number of variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-a-variable-number-of-variables)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use something like this:

```
for s in sheets:
    vars()['df'+ s] = pd.read_excel(xls, sheet_name=s)
```

Comment: What will be the dataframe name here?. Does it start with `df` followed by sheetname or just the sheetname? Because, when I follow this solution. I don't get the dataframe name?

Comment: The name will start with `df` followed by the sheetname. For example if the sheetname are `Sheet1` and `Sheet2`, the name of the dfs will be: `dfSheet1` and `dfSheet2` (it is the name in the square brackets: `df`+s)

Answer (score 2):

Strictly speaking not an answer to your question but this will create a dictionary where the key is the sheet name and the value is the dataframe.

```
workbook = pd.read_excel('DC_Measurement.xlsx', sheet_name = None)
```

Then you can retrieve the dataframe you need like this.

```
df = workbook['sheet_name']
```

I think this is tidier than other solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Or use `locals`:

```
for s in sheets:
    locals()['df'+ s] = pd.read_excel(xls, sheet_name=s)
```

In a function change `locals` to `globals`.

Answer (score 1):

The best approach is usually to store the dataframes in a list or dictionary, where you can work with them systematically, like this:

```
xls = pd.ExcelFile('DC_Measurement.xlsx')
sheets = {}
for s in xls.sheet_names:
    print(s)
    sheets[s] = pd.read_excel(xls, sheet_name=s)
```

Or just this:

```
xls = pd.ExcelFile('DC_Measurement.xlsx')
sheets = {
    s: pd.read_excel(xls, sheet_name=s)
    for s in xls.sheet_names
}
```

This will make it easy to work with the sheets programmatically later (just access `sheets[s]`, where `s` is a sheet name). Otherwise you will next face the tricky problem of how to access all the dataframes that you've just created as free-floating variables.